# Using the value of a JSON object that is stored in a PostgreSQL JSON array

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, json

I have a table that looks like this (simplified):

```
Jobs
-------------------------------
ID | Details
-------------------------------
1  | { 'tasks': [] }
2  | { 'tasks': [{'id': '1', 'due_on': '2015-06-8'}, {'id': '2', 'due_on': '2015-06-09'}] }
3  | { 'tasks': [{'id': '3','due_on': '2015-06-8'}] }
```

I am trying to query for two different things, both based on the `due_on` date in the subtasks:

1. The job id of all jobs that have a task due on a specific date
2. The tasks that are due on a specific date along with their job id

With a normalized structure these would obviously be easy queries. In this case, the data is structured as a JSON object for a very specific reason that's out of this question's scope. Let's just go with it.

I have been experimenting with the [JSON functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) and the [array functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/arrays.html) but I just can't seem to get the query right.

For example, `SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE Details->'tasks'->>'due_on' = '2015-06-08'` just throws a `cannot extract field from a non-object` error (for pretty clear reasons).

Alternatively, I could store the data as a `tasks` object instead of an array. If the above would be much easier / faster / better then I'll refactor.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: @Colin'tHart Unfortunately I don't seem to have many of the queries in my psql history. Most of my attempts involved thinking of it like a straight forward query:  `SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE "Details" -> 'tasks' ->> 'due_on' = '2015-08-09'` style. I kept trying to figure out the where query.. I wasn't even thinking of breaking it into a join like @Andomar suggested below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json_array_elements` to turn a JSON array into a rowset:

```
SELECT  "ID" as JobId
,       t->>'id' as TaskId
FROM    Table1 j
CROSS JOIN
        json_array_elements("Details"->'tasks') t
WHERE   cast(t->>'due_on' as date) = '2015-06-08';
```

The `cast(... as date)` works around the `2015-06-8` date which misses a leading `0` before the day.  If your format is always `YYYYMMDD`, you can omit the cast.

Comment: Awesome. I wouldn't have thought to use a `CROSS JOIN` like that. I think my understanding of what's returned by `json_array_elements` was lacking.